# Get rgb values out of string like rgb(49, 49, 50)

Tags: ruby, regex

From an input that follows this format:

```
rgb(49, 49, 50) or rgb(30,30,40)
```

How can I get a string that will just contain the numbers separated by commas, such as:

```
49,49,50
```

In Ruby? I am concerned about the case that sometimes there might be a space right after a comma. How can I deal with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scan is your friend:

```
"rgb(12,23,34)".scan(/\d+/).join(',') # => "12,23,34"
```

Nice and sweet.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) you can return an array of all matches. In this case `\d+` matches one or more digits. This returns an array  `['12','23','34']`. Then you can join the elements with commas.

```
"rgb(12,23,34)".scan(/\d+/).join(",")
#=> "12,23,34"
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this (ignores all the whitespace inside `rgb()`:

```
if "rgb(49, 49, 50)" =~ /rgb\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/
    [$1, $2, $3].join ","
end
#=> "49,49,50"
```

`R`, `G` and `B` will be in match groups 1 through 3, accessible via `$1`, `$2`, `$3` or returned result. [Try it out on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/NBHEhhv5sm).

**Update:** The difference between this solution and the ones using `scan` in here, that this one validates the input and won't match if the input is incorrect. It's probably a bit slower and longer to type than the `scan` solution. So `scan` solution would be a better choice when it's known a priori that then input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
new_str = "rgb(49, 49, 50)".sub(/rgb\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/, '\1,\2,\3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Very quickly, you could do something like this:

```
s1 = "rgb(30,30,40)"
s2 = "rgb(30, 30, 40)"

r = /rgb\((\d{1,3}),\s?(\d{1,3}),\s?(\d{1,3})\)/

m = r.match(s1)
puts "#{m[1]},#{m[2]},#{m[3]}" => 30,30,40

m = r.match(s2)
puts "#{m[1]},#{m[2]},#{m[3]}" => 30,30,40
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety, remove the characters you don't want:

```
"rgb(49, 49 , 50)".gsub(/[rgb() ]/, '')
=> "49,49,50"
```